# Accessing a Variable within a Delegate Stub

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

I have a variable, `tagToIndex` that exists within the stub of a delegate. It looks like this:

```
 func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt   index: Int) {
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)
    print(tagToIndex)

}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}

}
```

Currently, this exists within the class `MyCell`. I want to be able to access it in another class called `AnswerViewController`.

I tried using delegation to pass `tagToIndex` to `AnswerViewController`, but as far as I can tell I would simply end up with `tagToIndex` in another stub that is in AnswerViewController instead.

My question is: is there any way to access `tagToIndex` from another class (`AnswerViewController`), or even within the class it is already in (`MyCell`)?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: If I understand correctly your `tagToIndex` exists in both `MyCell` and `AnswerViewController` and you want to access to it at anytime and anywhere. If so, why don't you make it as a variable in a `sharedInstance` class?

Comment: you question is not clear, please explain it in a better way.